# Excel add-in password text box

Tags: c#, authentication, ribbon, excel-addins

I want make authentication in Excel Add-in Ribbon and sign in form is build in Ribbon (no modal window) but I need hide password characted in password text box. Ribbon don't allow add to group text box so I use edit box for enter login and password.

Do you know how can I set up "set_PasswordChar" for text box in ribbon?

Answer (score 1):

You can't there is no event to trap like onkeyup. The only way is to spown a form and manage the login outside the ribbons componet.

The only event on RibbonEditBos is TextChanged and Dispose.

For the TextChanged u can't trap single char mod. It fire when u submit the mods.

Answer (score 0):

On the onkeyup event, take the character out of the textbox, and replace it with an * store this into a variable to capture the password, then you just show a series of "********" in the text box. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Sure I have the same idea, but I thing this isn't clear solution :)

Comment: I don't know of another option. Good luck.